# Rewrite root to subfolder (.htaccess) except some directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes, url-rewriting

I have the following folder structure:

- app/ (contains index.php, js/, public/)
- v1/
- .htaccess

Requests to v1 should work as usual.
All other requests should go to /app without changing the URL

```
www.xxx.com/           (displays: app/index.php)
www.xxx.com/v1         (displays: v1/index.php)
www.xxx.com/js/xxx.js  (displays: app/js/xxx.js)
```

Is this possible?

**Basically, static folders:** v1, app/js (without app), app/public (without app)

All other requests go to **app/index.php** without URL changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# landing page
RewriteRule ^/?$ app/index.php [L]

# if v1/file exists then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/v1/$1 -f
RewriteRule .+ v1/$0 [L]

# if app/public/file exists then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule .+ app/public/$0 [L]

# if app/js/file exists then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/js/$1 -f
RewriteRule .+ app/js/$0 [L]

# if not a file, not a dir and not starting with v1    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^v1/ app/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Tried this, when going to www.xxx.com I got a page not found.
Not sure if my domain host has some weird apache settings that maybe needs to be overwritten.

Comment: Yes it does, a lot of the options I've found which are supposed to work don't. I have one.com as domain host, maybe there are some apache settings on their end that needs to be overwritten?

Comment: .htaccess is enabled and I've fixed stuff in here before. However none of the tips I've been given regarding this issue has seemed to work.

Comment: I just got it working, will update the post with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite requests from `/root` to `/subfoldwr` you can use the following Rule in your `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /app/index.php  [L]
```

This will rewrite everything except **existing files/directories** from your `/root` fodder to the `/app/index.php`  .