# .htaccess rewrite all routes except some to a different directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, single-page-application, vitepress

I have trouble combining redirection in .htaccess and internal rewriting too have a Vitepress home page to a website:

There are several sub directories containing their own websites, for example:

```
/app-a/*
/app-b/*
```

Requests with one of those as base should remain unchanged.
All other requests should be prefixed with `/home`, so `/about` would become `/home/about` and so on.
This should be a redirect that's visible to the client.

However additionally, `/home/` should serve `/home/index.html`, while `/home/about` should either serve `/home/about.html` or `/home/about/index.html` (depending on which one of those exists).
This should not be a redirect visible to the client (only if the client requests `/home/index.html` it should get redirected to `/home/`).

So the process would be:

1. Is it one of the sub-directories that exist? If so, keep it unchanged.
2. Else make it point to `/home/...`
3. Determine the HTML file to serve (either `<path>.html` or `<path>/index.html`).

I found many similar questions but none that combined the two requirements and I was not able to get it to work myself. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052754/11793652) for example explains how to exclude some folders, but it explicitly states which subfolders to exclude - even inside the `/home/` directory.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/home/index.html  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/app-a/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/app-b/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/home/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /home$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of screwing around, I was able to make it work in most cases using this config:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R,L]

# redirect from <path>.html to <path>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

# serve <path>.html when requesting <path>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

# serve /home/<path> if /<path> is no file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /home/$1 [L]

# serve /index (/home/index.html) at root
RewriteRule ^$ /index [L]

# 404 error page
ErrorDocument 404 /home/404.html
```

However, this solution is not perfect.
I still have the problem that 404s are not treated correctly.

- When I request a nonexistent page like `/abc123/`, I get a 500 error.
- When I request a page that is a file as a directory like `/about/` instead of `/about`, I get a 301 error.